# How to make keybd_event handle more than two key presses at once?

Tags: c#, winapi

Im using keybd_event win api call in C# and i want to simulate special key presses, like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and similar. My program can handle "simple" key presses, like <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and simple use of <kbd>tab</kbd>, or <kbd>enter</kbd> are also working, but when two special buttons present (for special buttons i mean <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or functional buttons) it seems it does nothing. My program should handle multiple forms through remote desktop, thats why im using this keybd_event call, but for example <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> doesnt work even locally (im testing on a notepad, but i cannot close it with this command). Anyone has idea what am i doing wrong? Is it even possible to make them work?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I have created a DLLImport class in which i stored all the win api calls. I also have some helper methods, for example:

```
private void PressAlt()
    {
        DLLImport.keybd_event(0xA0, 0x38, 0, 0);
    }

private void ReleaseAlt()
    {
        DLLImport.keybd_event(0xA0, 0x38, 0x0002, 0);
    }
```

For tab, im using this in a separate method:

```
DLLImport.keybd_event(0x09, 0x0f, 0, 0); //press tab
```

...

```
DLLImport.keybd_event(0x09, 0x0f, 0x0002, 0); //release tab
```

And im now testing it with:

```
PressAlt();

PressSpecial("tab");

ReleaseSpecial("tab");

ReleaseAlt();
```

Comment: Can you show some source code? It's difficult to identify problems with nothing to see.

Comment: I have edited my question (my apology, im still new at this forum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, it looks like you have the wrong values for at least one of the virtual key codes ([MSDN reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

For example, the code `0xA0` is the Left Shift key (`VK_LSHIFT`), you should try `0x12` (`VK_MENU`) or `0xA4` (`VK_LMENU`) instead.

Note - there is a useful summary of common virtual key codes and scan codes [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7305/Keyboard-Events-Simulation-using-keybd_event-funct).